# IntegrationTests for Spring IntegrationFlow

Tags: spring-integration

I am having trouble in writing test cases for my IntegrationFlow which is using Spring Integration DSL. Below is my code snippet and I would like to test the 'transform' part. Please provide some help in mocking the handle part or if there is some other way to test this -

```
public class DmwConfig {
    @Value("${dmw.url.hostname}")
    public String hostName;

    @Bean
    public MessageChannel dmwGetProductDetailsByEanChannel() {
        return MessageChannels.direct().get();
    }

    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow dmwGetProductDetailsByEan() {
        return IntegrationFlows
                .from("input")
                .channel("dmwGetProductDetailsByEanChannel")
                .handle(httpMessageHandlerSpec())
                .<JsonNode, ProductModel>transform(
                        node -> new ProductModel(
                            node.findValue("name").asText(null),
                            node.findValue("inventory").findValue("orderable").asBoolean(false),
                            node.findValue("stock_level").asInt(0),
                            node.findValue("price").asDouble(0),
                            "", // this url field will be enriched in the controller because the url doesn't contain any data from the response
                            node.findValue("image_groups").findValue("link").asText(null)
                        )
                )
                .get();
    }

    @Bean
    public HttpRequestExecutingMessageHandler httpMessageHandlerSpec() {
        return Http
                .outboundGateway((Message<DmwPayload> p) -> "foobar url")
                .charset("UTF-8")
                .httpMethod(HttpMethod.GET)
                .expectedResponseType(JsonNode.class).get();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

We don't have [mocking framework](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-java-dsl/issues/23) yet, but that is really intention in the nearest future.

You can consider to use `@MockBean` from the latest [Spring Boot](https://spring.io/blog/2016/04/15/testing-improvements-in-spring-boot-1-4) for your `HttpRequestExecutingMessageHandler httpMessageHandlerSpec` to replace that bean with desired mock.

On the other hand you can just send message directly to the [input channel](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-java-dsl/wiki/Spring-Integration-Java-DSL-Reference#message-channels) for that your `.transform`. Please, read that manual from the phrase:

> By default endpoints are wired via DirectChannel where the bean name is based on the pattern: [IntegrationFlow.beanName].channel#[channelNameIndex].

So, required channel in your flow has bean name like: `dmwGetProductDetailsByEan.channel#0`, because this is a first unnamed channel in your IntegrationFlow definition.